# / root filesystem has 0 bytes of space left

Tags: root, disk-usage

A few minutes ago I received a notification stating that there's only some 600 MB of space left in filesystem root. I went through `/var/log` and cleared the following files:

```
syslog
kern.log
lern.log.1
syslog.1
```

But these files hardly freed an space. I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

which only cleared 1.3 gigs of space. I have no idea what is eating up so much space, the root filesystem has a max limit of 59.8 gigs. Every time I reload the `+ Other Locations` page in file manager, the space left on the root partition keeps going down. As I mentioned before 1.3G of space was saved, which kept going down and down as I was reloading the page every time (see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nmg5cDQQr0bXAd4olrjRacD_N5_0RWne/view?usp=sharing)). I have no idea where so much of space is being used. I noticed there is a volume that got created ever since I faced this issue, called "163 MB Volume" with 163M of space, at /dev/loop1 which also now has 0 bytes of space left. I also ran `sudo du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 20` which failed to execute:

```
vaidik@unknown:/etc$ sudo du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 20
du: cannot access '/proc/68370': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/69299/task/69299/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/69299/task/69299/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/69299/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/69299/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
sort: write failed: /tmp/sortqzVDKC: No space left on device
```

I used `sudo find / -size +1G` which returned a few files, one of them was <2G and other one which it suggested is proc/kcore which says is 140TB... I think there's something wrong with Ubuntu here because my system's SSD does not have 140TB of space?

**Update:** I just rebooted my system and now it says I have 11.9G of space left. But the cause of the situation is still unknown, I still need help with finding the cause of all of this.

Comment: There is something in my system that is eating up space drastically. As shown in the video, the space left keeps going down. Even when I try to delete my personal files...Just can't figure out what is causing this.

Comment: things to consider: if you use a server or printers: log files in /var/log/. If you use a desktop: snaps (those take up a lot of space).

Comment: You can use the command `sudo lsof +D /` to list all open files on `/`. Simply removing a file (even `sudo rm  -f`) does not reclaim the space IF a process has the file open. The process thinks it's writing/appending to a file it opened long ago, and wants to write the "next" block of the file. Until the process closes the file, the space cannot be released. Read `man lsof kill pkill` and the `man` page for the process you found with `lsof`.

Comment: Rather than making us guess your product/release details; it's easier if you tell us what Ubuntu product you're asking about.